Unable to pip install google.cloud.sql.connector when building docker image
I am using Python developing a web app in my local machine. I am using the code from Connect using Cloud SQL Language Connectors to connect to my GCP Postgres database and working fine! However, when I building the docker image using docker file, I failed at the step of "RUN pip install google-cloud-sql-connector" which is the connector that I use in my coding in order to connect to GCP Postgres.
The error shows as below:
# [13/13] RUN pip install google-cloud-sql-connector:
# 0.911 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement google-cloud-sql-connector    (from versions: none)
# 0.911 ERROR: No matching distribution found for google-cloud-sql-connector
# # ------
# ****Dockerfile:15
# # --------------------**
# 13 | RUN pip install pg8000
# 14 | RUN pip install google-cloud-secret-manager
# 15 | >>> RUN pip install google-cloud-sql-connector
# 16 | CMD ["python","main.py"]
# 17 |
# # --------------------**
# ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c pip install google-cloud-sql-connector" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Please can anyone of you help? Thank you.
Help to resolve the error

What Python version is running in the docker container?

There are two different database drivers that are supported for the Postgres dialect.
pg8000
pip install "cloud-sql-python-connector[pg8000]"

asyncpg
pip install "cloud-sql-python-connector[asyncpg]"

here is the details
